# Is it possible to have people join your singleplayer world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to get people to join your singleplayer world if they are connected to your LAN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the version 1.3.1 a option was added to the menu in Single Player games, "Open to LAN"

> **Added option to let LAN friends join SP games**
>
> You can choose which
> gamemode players join in and whether they are allowed to use cheats.
>
> in [Version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about others joining you can always Open to LAN, but if you want to use a server instead you can go into `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\saves` and find the world you are looking for. After finding it, you can place the files under `%APPDATA%\.minecraft\saves\<WORLDNAME>` into a folder named `World` in the same directory as a minecraft server. If you need help setting up a server, see the Minecraft Wiki page for [setting up a server](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can have people join your world if it is offline. It is called opening the world to lan through pausing the game and choosing the option OPEN TO LAN... Make sure you have internet connection.

Comment: Open to LAN should not require an internet connection; LAN and internet are two different things.